# Possible have matrix rows collapsed by default in the Control Panel?

Tags: matrix, control-panel

Is it possible to have all Matrix rows in the Control Panel entry be in the collapsed state by default?

Thanks.
Lori

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inject this piece of JS in your CP and they will always be closed by default:

```
$('.matrixblock').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('collapsed');
    Craft.MatrixInput.rememberCollapsedBlockId($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Here's an example plugin that will inject it in the CP: https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/6bb9e5296977a99c39b1

Comment: Great to hear!  What file do I add that code into?

Comment: Its best to create a new plugin for it and make the `init()` function include the js. I've created a gist that should set you up: https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/6bb9e5296977a99c39b1

Comment: Or you could just use [CP JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) ;)

Comment: I can't get this working with CP JS in Craft 2 — the class is being appended but the field is still open... looks like the style needs to be changed too?

[EDIT: maybe it's because the matrix field is inside a Supertable?]

Comment: This would be handy to have just as a setting in the fieldtype.

Comment: This used to work great. But does not seem to work in Craft 3.5. Any tips for updating?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of, but this feature request and response may at least help a bit. http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7425151--expand-collapse-all-ui-for-matrix-fields

Comment: While its true that this doesn't come out of the box, it easily can be done.